# Handle n menu items in template engine

Tags: python, template-engine

I need to create N menu items, with possible  N childs.

This works great for one level.

```
items = {'link1': 'value1', 
         'link2': 'value2', 
         'link3': 'value3'
         }
```

---

```
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        {% for key in items %}
        <li>
           <a href="{{ escape(key) }}"> {{ escape(items[key]) }}</a>
        </li
       {% end %}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

That will output:

```
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="link1"> value1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="link2"> value2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="link3"> value3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

But if i have a more complex structure like this, how can handle that?

```
level 1
   level 1.1
   level 1.2
   level 1.3
level 2
   level 2.1
      level 2.1.1
          level 2.1.1.1
      level 2.1.2
level 3
   level 3.1
   level 3.2
```

Comment: Good question, succinct examples, attempts shown. Thanks. But you're going to have to create a custom filter, I think.

Comment: What template engine are You using? I have an example of django templatetag solving similar task, but is it what you're looking for?

Comment: @alko, tornado.template http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/template.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list of dicts instead, and allow each dict to have a "children" key. Example for a "two levels" menu:

```
items = [
    {'label': 'label1', 
     'link': 'link1',
     'children': [
         {'label':'label1.1', 'link': 'link1.1'}, 
         {'label':'label1.2', 'link': 'link1.2'} 
         ]
     },
    {'label': 'label2', 
     'link': 'link2',
     'children': [
         {'label':'label2.1', 'link': 'link2.1'}, 
         {'label':'label2.2', 'link': 'link2.2'} 
         ]
     },
    # etc
    ]
```

Then in your template:

```
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        {% for item in items %}
        <li>
           <a href="{{ escape(item['link']) }}"> {{ escape(item['label']) }}</a>
           {% if 'children' in item %}
           <ul>
             {% for child in item['children'] %}
             <li>
               <a href="{{ escape(child['link']) }}"> {{ escape(child['label']) }}</a>
             </li>
             {% end %}
           </ul>
           {% end %}
        </li
       {% end %}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

If you want to be able to handle any arbitray depth, you'll need some recursion mechanism in your template but since I don't know what template engine you're using I can't help much here.

Comment: This _is_ a more sound approach. Still working on a way to iterate over nested structures. The problem is most solutions are recursive, and thats a little difficult to do.

Comment: @loops: yes I could, but I wont - it's trivial and it's _your_ job, not mine. Just a hint : dont use "children_0" / "children_1" in your data structure, just "children", you _do_ want an uniform structure whatever the depth.

Comment: @loops: oh and yes: if your teplate engine has any kind of inclusion mechanism (which should be the case), solving the "arbitrary depth" problem is trivial too. As with any tree structure, recursion is your friend.

Comment: @loops: I don't know what's a "PHP programmer" is. Either you're a programmer or you're not. If you can solve this "problem" in PHP you can easily solve it with Python and tornado.template.

Answer (score 0):

There is one way to do this iteration, and that is understanding its types. So, say you have lists, and inside this list you have strings, and lists. So, this is how I would go about it:

```
{% if key.get_type == "list" %}
    {% for var in key %}
     ... (this will only work for as many levels as you define)
```

Answer (score 0):

To see the output as a nested list, use this:
(Im assuming you already have the `items` dictionary in a similar format.)

```
items = [
{'link': 'link1','value': 'value1',
 'sub_items': [
       {'link':'link1.1','value':'value1.1'},
       {'link':'link1.2','value':'value1.2'},
       {'link':'link1.3','value':'value1.3'},
  ]
 },
 {'link': 'link2','value': 'value2',
  'sub_items': [
       {'link':'link2.1','value':'value2.1',
        'sub_items': [
            {'link':'link2.1.1','value':'value2.1.1',
             'sub_items': [
                {'link':'link2.1','value':'value2.1.1.1'}
             ]
            }
        ]
       }
  ]
 },
 {'link': 'link3','value': 'value3',
  'sub_items': [
       {'link':'link3.1','value':'value3.1'}
  ]
 }
]
```

---

In your template:

```
<nav id="menu">
<ul>
{% for item in items %}
  <li>
    <a href="{{ item.link }}"> {{ item.value }}</a>
    {% if item.sub_items %}
      <ul>
      {% for item2 in item.sub_items %}
        <li>
        <a href="{{ item2.link }}"> {{ item2.value }}</a>
        {% if item2.sub_items %}
          <ul>
          {% for item3 in item2.sub_items %}
            <li>
            <a href="{{ item3.link }}"> {{ item3.value }}</a>
            {% if item3.sub_items %}
              <ul>
                {% for item4 in item3.sub_items %}
                  <li>
                    <a href="{{ item4.link }}"> {{ item4.value }}</a>
                  </li>
                {% endfor %}
              </ul>
            {% endif %}
            </li>
          {%endfor%}
          </ul>
        {% endif %}
        </li>
      {%endfor%}
      </ul>
    {% endif %}
  </li>
{%endfor%}
</ul>
</nav>
```

It will produce the desired output.

Comment: endif is not supported. Anyway replaced by end works, but i am still getting , if item2["sub_items"]:  # index.html:30 KeyError: 'sub_items'

Comment: @loops I have updated my answer. That error is coming because of differences in template engine. You can update the html according to your syntax.